# DIVs that are aware of their position, or the window's scroll position?

Tags: jquery

In jQuery, how do you make it so a DIV will stay put until the user scrolling down would make it no longer visible (at which point it sets its own CSS position to "fixed")? It's a trick I see a lot, just not sure how it's done.

Example: http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=sushi&ns=1&find_loc=San+Francisco%2C+CA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick example of some code:

```
var standardPosition = $('div').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > standardPosition) $('div').css('position','fixed');
    else $('div').css('position','relative');
});
```

It's important to store the starting position somewhere, so you know when you've scrolled up far enough to restore it to whatever position it was in.

http://jsfiddle.net/qC6HB/

Comment: Be aware that in some browsers (I'm looking at you Internet Explorer) the scroll event fires continually when scrolling. Using a plugin like [Ben Alman's Throttle/Debounce](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) prevents situations like that.

Comment: @devmatt: It doesn't prevent it, it just masks it. Which could would be the same as setting a timeout and clearing it every time it fires. The timeout duration would be the 'delay' in his plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a Sticky Scroller.  Take a look at this: [jQuery Sticky Scroller / Position:Fixed Plugin](http://www.vertstudios.com/blog/jquery-sticky-scroller-position-fixed-plugin/)

[Simple Demo](http://vertstudios.com/blog/demo/stickyscroller/demo.php)

Answer (score 0):

Check with `$(window).scroll()` the Y-position of the `window`, and once it reaches > than the Y-position of the div element (which you can get with `offset()`) you can change the css to fixed.

Something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){
    var e = $('div').offset();
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > e.top){
     $('div').css('position','fixed').css('top',0);   
    }else{
    $('div').css('position','static');  
    }


});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/HUxVC/